# How to make the navigation item to be active on selected?

Tags: php, html, navigation

I have removed the the navigation part from all the files and kept in a separate file named nav.php and then called it at the required place as

```
 include ('includes/nav.php');
```

The content of the nav.php file is as follows:

```
<ul>
       <li<?php if ($thisPage=="http://www.finalyearondesk.com")
            echo " class=\"selected\""; ?>>
               <a href="http://www.finalyearondesk.com">Home</a></li>

       <li<?php if ($thisPage=="http://www.finalyearondesk.com/contact.php") 
            echo " class=\"selected\""; ?>>
               <a href="http://www.finalyearondesk.com/contact.php">Contact US</a></li>

       <li<?php if ($thisPage=="http://www.finalyearondesk.com/downloads.php") 
            echo " class=\"selected\""; ?>>
               <a href="http://www.finalyearondesk.com/downloads.php">Downloads</a></li>
</ul>
```

But the problem is I can not get the current item selected when that page is visited.
What is wrong is with my code?

Comment: the var $thisPage equals what?

Comment: I have three pages that I need to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not assigning value to $thisPage. Add this following code before the ul in nav.php

```
<?php
$protocol = strpos(strtolower($_SERVER['SERVER_PROTOCOL']),'https') 
                === FALSE ? 'http' : 'https';
$host     = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'];
$script   = $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'];

$thisPage = $protocol . '://' . $host . $script;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

make sure, you are assigning full url to $thisPage and that should be before your line

```
include ('includes/nav.php');
```

because in your niv.php you are not assigning $thisPage